# Mongoose / MongoDB duplicate entries with unique key in schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I dont know why this happens, I have a schema with a unique key for the field "address" but I get duplicate entries. I also check before I insert a new document if Model.exists() and it still inserts documents. I have no idea why, also I am getting occasional duplicate entry errors in the console. This is my code

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        address    : { type: String, unique: true },
        isContract : { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false },
        ethervalue : { type: Number, default: 0 },
        symbol     : { type: String, unique: true },
        tokenname : { type: String},
        divisor   : { type: Number },
        tokentype : {type: String},
        bluecheckmark: {type : Boolean, default: false},
        description: {type: String},
        totalsupply: {type: Number},
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

```
async saveAddress(address) {
        try {
            const exists = await Address.exists({ address: address });
            if (!exists) {
                const isContract = await this.isContract(address);
                let temp = new Address();
                if (isContract) {
                    const info = await etherscan.getTokenInfoByContractAddress(address);
                    temp.isContract = true;
                    if(info.status == 1){       
                        temp.symbol = info.result[0].symbol;
                        temp.tokenname = info.result[0].tokenName;
                        temp.totalsupply = info.result[0].totalSupply;
                        temp.divisor =  info.result[0].divisor;
                        temp.tokentype = info.result[0].tokenType;
                        temp.description = info.result[0].description
                        temp.bluecheckmark = info.result[0].blueCheckmark
                    }
                }

                temp.address = address;
                await temp.save();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('saveAddres()', error.message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turns out `unique` is not respected if:

- Your collection already contains duplicates.
- Your collection has a document where the unique field is undefined.

I removed all duplicates with the query from this blog post: https://www.totally-nerdy.com/blog/post/18849/how-to-find-and-remove-duplicates-in-mongodb/

However, I had to change it slightly for MongoDB Compass to swallow it:

```
db.collectionName
  .aggregate(
    [
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$uniqueField",
          dups: { $push: "$_id" },
          count: { $sum: 1 },
        },
      },
      { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } },
    ],
    { allowDiskUse: true }
  ).toArray()
  .forEach(async function (doc) {
    doc.dups.shift();
    await db.collectionName.deleteOne({ _id: { $in: doc.dups } });
  });
```

Replace `uniqueField`, and `collectionName` in two places.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent duplicate entries in mongodb, you can add a unique index on that particular field. In this case: `db.collection.createIndex({"address":1},{unique:true})` .
Refer: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: but I already have a field with a unique property: true which shows up as an index on atlas. So that cant be it, did you see my schema above?

Comment: The only way it gets added again is if it enters  if(!exists) condition, that means the Address.exists() isnt working as expected? maybe try replacing with findOne() or countDocuments().